# Problem with markdown formatting - how to display code correctly

Tags: git, github, markdown

I have a short README.md where I have problems in formatting.

https://github.com/wojciehm/macOS-.bash_profile-cron-backup

[image: Image with description]

I can't paste the raw code because SO wants to format it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an HTML `<br>` tag, i.e.

```
4. We commit all files with comment from script execution time
`date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`;<br>`git commit -a -m "generated files on date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'"`;
```

Note that I think the whole thing is more readable like [this](https://github.com/alexharv074/bash-test#test).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to ignore the `` ` ``backtick inside, you can do it this way

```
``inline containing backtick ` ``
```

this will output `` inline containing backtick ` ``

Comment: I tried that as well but with some error. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

There are some examples in the [GitHub Flavored Markdown docs](https://github.github.com/gfm/#list-items) that cover this, but the short version is that you simply need to indent the code block.

For example:

```
4. We commit all files with comment from script execution time: ` "generated files on date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'";`

  `git commit -a -m "generated files on date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'";`
```

^ note the two space characters at the beginning of the last line.

This renders to:

4. We commit all files with comment from script execution time:  `"generated files on date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'";`

   `git commit -a -m "generated files on date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'";`